# Вместо POST получаю метод GET при передаче переменных

Tags: javascript, php, html

Форма

```
<div class="modal fade textMonsterrat" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true" align="left">
                 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                   <div class="modal-content">
                     <div class="modal-header">
                       <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle"><strong>Оформление заказа</strong></h5>
                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                       </button>
                     </div>
                     <div class="modal-body">
                       <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/wp-content/themes/zip_theme/page-telegramcart.php/" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Ваше имя</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="user_name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя" required>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Ваш телефон</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" name="user_phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон" required>
                        </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Ваш E-mail</label>
                             <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="user_email" placeholder="Email" data-error="Вы не правильно ввели Ваш E-mail" required>
                             <input type="hidden" id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" />
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Сообщение</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text" placeholder="Введите текст" name="user_text"></textarea>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Прикрепите файл с вашими реквизитами или другой необходимой информацией</label>
                            <input type="file" name="myfile[]" multiple id="myfile" class="form-control-file btn">
                          </div>
                         <div class="form-group modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                              <button id="sendmail" formmethod="post" class="sendEmail btn btn-primary">Отправить</button>
                         </div>
                       </form>  
                     </div>


                    </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
```

Вместе с формой отправляются и другие данные из localStorage: код на JS

```
function sendEmail() {
    var massaplits = $('.price-cartplits').val();
    var summaplits = $('.weight-cartplits').val();
    var massavtul = $('.price-cartvtul').val();
    var summavtul = $('.weight-cartvtul').val();
    console.log(cartweight1);
    if (ename!='' && Email!='' && ephone!=''){
    if(isEmpty(cart) || isEmpty(cartvtul) || isEmpty(cartplits)){
        $.post(
        "https://castpolymer.ru/wp-content/themes/zip_theme/page-telegramcart.php",
                { 
                    "cart" : cart,
                    "cart1" : cart1,
                    "massasterj" : cartweight1,
                    "summasterj" : cartprice1,
                    "cartplits" : cartplits,
                    "cartplits1" : cartplits1,
                    "massaplits" : plitweight,
                    "summaplits" : plitprice,
                    "cartvtul" : cartvtul,
                    "cartvtul1" : cartvtul1,
                    "massavtul" : vtulweight,
                    "summavtul" : vtulprice,
                    "itogs" : itogs,
                    "itogm" : itogm


                },
            function(data){
                    if (data==1){
                        document.location.href = "https://mysite.ru/thanks";

                    }
                else {

                    document.location.href = "https://mysite.ru/wp-content/themes/zip_theme/page-telegramcart.php";

//                    localStorage.clear();
                }
                }

        );
    }
        else {
            alert('Корзина пуста!');
        }
    }
    else {
        alert('Заполните поля');
    }

}
```

На выходе PHP получаю вот что:
[image: Вместо POST получаю GET]

Comment: Минус чисто за ajax... Раз берётесь за wp то и использовать надо его средства для ajax, а не костылять подобным образом. А по теме - используйте `$.ajax()`

Comment: что-то мне кажется что это ваш заход на саму страницу,а не аяксовый пост.

Comment: Да костыльный метод, а как лучше всего реализовать через ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Вот это GET который виден

`document.location.href = "https://mysite.ru/wp-content/themes/zip_theme/page-telegramcart.php";`

Ставим галочку `Preserve log`, и будет виден POST.

Comment: XHR finished loading: POST "https://castpolymer.ru/wp-content/themes/zip_theme/page-telegramcart.php".
send @ VM9342 jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ VM9342 jquery.min.js:4
n.<computed> @ VM9342 jquery.min.js:4
otpravit @ VM9339 cartAssort.js:662
dispatch @ VM9336 jquery.js:3
r.handle @ VM9336 jquery.js:3
Navigated to https://castpolymer.ru/wp-content/themes/zip_theme/page-telegramcart.php